# Yum says a package is installed, and not installed, and it's blocking other packages from being installed

Tags: centos, yum, glibc

I am trying to install a new package (`glibc-static`), and I get the following error

```
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-18.el6_6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.i686 (CentOS-OS)
          Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6
          Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64 (@updates)
              glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
          Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (CentOS-OS)
              glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6.i686 (CentOS-OS)
          Requires: glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6
          Installed: glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64 (@updates)
              glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
          Available: glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 (CentOS-OS)
              glibc-headers = 2.12-1.149.el6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Notice that `glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64` and `glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64` don't match. But `glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64` is listed as being available. I would think that yum would happily install it. Unforunately, yum didn't install it.

So I tried to do it myself.

```
~ $> sudo yum install glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
Package matching glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

That didn't work. It thinks it is already installed.

So I tried to reinstall it.

```
~ $> sudo yum reinstall glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No Match for argument: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6
Package(s) glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6 available, but not installed.
Nothing to do
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Messing with the RPM database didn't yield any particularly good results.

I ended up noticing that some of the `glibc` packages were `i686` and others were `x86_64`. For instance:

```
Package: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.i686 (CentOS-OS)
    Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.149.el6
    Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
```

I didn't like that, and I expect that Yum didn't like that either.

Running

```
yum downgrade glibc glibc-headers glibc-common glibc-devel
```

brought all of the packages to the same architecture (`x86_64`). Then,

```
yum install glibc-static
```

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

The RPM DB is confused. My recommendation, having encountered this before, it to `rpm -e --justdb` the newer "duplicate" package installed, then `yum upgrade` the package, then `rpm --rebuilddb` just because I'm a bit of a paranoiac. Once you've gone through the first two steps, you should be able to install the newer packages, assuming your repo is properly in sync. You may want to `yum clean all` right after the `rpm -e --justdb` to be sure of that - and make darn sure you specify `--justdb` or you could do all sorts of bad things to your system.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work for me. `rpm -e --justdb glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64` failed and said that it `is needed by (installed) glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64`. So I added `--nodeps` and that command worked. The `upgrade` command didn't work; it said the package wasn't installed.  I tried to `install` it, and got `Protected multilib versions: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6.i686 != glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64`

Comment: You may have to adjust which version you `-e --justdb` based on what's going on with other `glibc-*` packages. It's going to take some trial and error to get completely correct. The important things to remember are the `--justdb` and the `-rebuilddb`. The latter you may want to run at several points in the process to be sure your RPMDB is semi-current.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve a similar issue by downloading the rpms manually to the system (note, you will need to have all the dependent rpm's) saving them to a folder and running:

yum localupdate /folderlocation/*.rpm

My issue revolved around yum finding inconsistencies when getting the RPM's from the repo's I was pointing to. The symptoms though presented exactly like what you are seeing so this may also work for you.